# Why is the programme returning: `<main>': undefined method `second' for main:Object (NoMethodError)?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

```
class Array

  attr_accessor :arr

  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
  end

  def self.second(list)
    if list[1] != nil
      puts list[1]
    else
      puts nil
    end
  end

end

([3, 4, 5]).second
```

Answer (score 0):

You've `second` as a class method instead of instance method.

Do this instead.

```
class Array

  def second
    if self[1].nil? 
      puts "Nil value"
    else  
      puts self[1]
    end
  end

end
```

And by the way you don't need an `attr_accessor`. That's a code smell.

Comment: I think that he tried to patch Array in order to add second method

Comment: Man you're a character. Aren't you? Don't you think we might be writing answers together and you just posted first. Don't be a crybaby.

Comment: And you didn't even explain you're changes. Why you removed `self` and all.

Comment: Of course sorry, you just edit your answer after see what I do, but it is not the important thing I hope that you have learned too something new :)

Comment: Sure man. One should always try to better himself. Thank you. I hope you also learned that voting someone's answer negative just because he has same answer as yours might not always be wise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83672/discussion-between-vjdhama-and-horacio-branciforte).

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `self` in the definition of a method makes the method a class and not an instance method.

At the moment your method can be called like this:

```
Array.second([3, 4, 5])
```

If you want to call is like this:

```
[3, 4, 5].second
```

then you need to change your code to something like this:

```
class Array
  def second
    if self[1] != nil
      puts self[1]
    else
      puts nil
    end
  end
end
```

Furthermore there is no need to check for `nil` if you print the `nil` anyway. This allows us to write the same as:

```
class Array
  def second
    puts(self[1])
  end
end

[3,4,5].second
#=> 4
[].second
#=>
```

If you want to explicitly print the string "nil" instead of just `nil`, change to code to:

```
puts(self[1] | 'nil')
```

Or:

```
puts(self.fetch(1) { 'nil' })
```